# ExtJS with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

I'm looking into the grid sample from ExtJS 4.0 documentation:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/guide/grid.html

I'd like to use that piece of code within ASP.NET MVC 3 application that I'm hosting on my local machine (Visual Studio developer host). However ExtJS 4.0 has lots of files and I'm wondering which files should I include into the project.

So, which files to include to get the basic ExtJS stuff working?

pom

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the ext-all.css file and ext-all.js file